# Python.Заполните массив случайными N - числами в интервале [0,5]. Найдите все значения равные X

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста!!! Задача в питоне
Заполните массив случайными N - числами в интервале [0,5]. Найдите все значения равные X.
Формат входных данных
N и X. N – целое число, в диапазоне от 1 до 1 000 000. X число в диапазоне от 0 до 5.
Формат выходных данных
Вывести полученный массив, в первой строке, каждый элемент через пробел. Далее - найденные значения индексов массива. По одному в каждой строке.
Пример
Входные данные

```
5 2
```

Выходные данные

```
12312
1
4
```

• 1 и 4 это индексы элементов массива равных X (2)

```
import random
n, x = map(int, input().split())
arr = [random.randint(0, 5) for i in range (0,n)]
print(*arr)
c = x
j = 0
while True:
    try:
        i = arr.index(c, j)
        print(i)
        j = i + 1
    except:
        break
```

Программа рабочая, но не прохожу по времени. Подскажите, какие еще есть варианты?

Comment: Отформатируйте код, чтобы его можно было прочитать

Comment: Всё ещё нельзя прочитать. В Питоне пробелы важны.

Answer (score 3):

```
b = [i for i in range(n) if arr[i] == x]
print(*b)
```

Comment: Хотя я бы использовал `enumerate(arr)`, но дело вкуса, конечно )

Comment: Спасибо большое! но нужно вывести каждый индекс с новой строки:                                                     b = [i for i in range(n) if arr[i] == x]
print('\n'.join(str(i) for i in b))         
и я опять не прохожу по времени....

Comment: @nad Зачем так сложно: `print(*b, sep='\n')`

Comment: Благодарю, уже попробовала - Time limit exceeded  все равно....

Comment: Создание и поиск теперь быстрые, время тратится на вывод. У меня 1.7 секунды тратится на вывод массива 1000000 в одну строчку, и 8 секунд на вывод отфильтрованного на отдельных строчках. И мне кажется, что для консольного вывода такого размера это не так уж плохо

Comment: У меня, к сожалению, на всю задачу ограничение по времени 2 сек...

Comment: Вы получили радикальное улучшение алгоритма вычислений с квадратичного до линейного. Консольный вывод примерно 200000 строк - дело не быстрое, на компилируемом языке я получил примерно то же время порядка 10 секунд.

Answer (score 0):

Используя `filter`:

```py
*res, = filter(lambda i: arr[i] == x, range(len(arr)))
```

с выводом:

```py
*map(print, filter(lambda i: arr[i]==x, range(len(arr)))),
```

Comment: двести тысяч строк за секунду в консоль умеете выводить?

Comment: @MBo, я все могу))

Comment: Дико извиняюсь, не совсем поняла с выводом....

Comment: @nad, с точки зрения, оптимального использования ресурсов, возможно этот вариант не подойдет, потому, что создается tuple. Попробуйте запустить `a = *range(4),` и вывести значение а. А возможно он и не создается, потому, что знака присвоения нет(т.е. tuple не используется).